# Trouble shooting with postgresql to connect with Django | Window 10

Tags: python, django, postgresql, fatal-error

I install PostgreSQL version 10

also, install pgAdmin4

During the PostgreSQL installation, as Every developer know default username = Postgres

My PostgreSQL username was Postgres.

installation window asked me the password, so put the new password

Now when I connect PostgreSQL to my Django project

I install this module

```
pip install psycopg2
```

I created a new database using pgAdmin4 named 'mydb'

In my Settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'mydb',
       'USERNAME':'postgres',
       'PASSWORD' : '<my_Password_here>' , # I entered the same password that i provided during postgres installation
       'HOST' : 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```

postgres username = 'postgres'

where

my Window Username = 'Huzaifa'

> ERROR is here

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Huzaifa"
```

Why Postgres using my Window User (username) for authentication

> NOTE:

I already set environment variables as following

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin

Answer (score 0):

After Posting this Question. I found what I was mistaking.

There is no Variable name USERNAME. change USERNAME to USER

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'mydb',
       'USERNAME':'postgres', # <-- Here is the Mistake -->
       'PASSWORD' : '<my_Password_here>' ,
       'HOST' : 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```

Change to...

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'mydb',
       'USER':'postgres', # <-- Here is the Mistake -->
       'PASSWORD' : '<my_Password_here>' ,
       'HOST' : 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```